# How to create asyncTask to prevent networkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, tcp, android-asynctask

I'm new to android application development. I tried to develop an android server client chat

for my first project. This is the code for the client side. When the client press `btnJoin`,

it will connect to the server and send a string. I've read many example and many of them

looks like this. I got a `networkOnMainThreadException`. How do I make an `asyncTask` to prevent

this problem? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
btnJoin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonJoin);
btnJoin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Socket socket = null;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket("192.168.1.4", 9092);
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Hello server!");
            txtIP.append(dataInputStream.readUTF() + "\n");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (dataOutputStream != null) {
                try {
                    dataOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (dataInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    dataInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @avd Thanks for editting my question. I'll format my next question properly. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code as:

```
   btnJoin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
   public void onClick(View view){

              new LongOperation().execute("");

    }
}

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
     Socket socket = null;
     String strresult="";
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            socket = new Socket("192.168.1.4", 9092);
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Hello server!");
            strresult.append(dataInputStream.readUTF() + "\n");
         //   txtIP.append(dataInputStream.readUTF() + "\n");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (dataOutputStream != null) {
                try {
                    dataOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (dataInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    dataInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

                return strresult;
          }      

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                TextView txtIP= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtIP);
              //  txtIP.append(result + "\n");
                txtIP.setText(result + "\n");

          }

          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {
          }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I followed your code and it seems to work. I added a line on void onPostExecute. Log.d("OnPostExecute","Done"). But the log never shows up. Any clue?

Comment: try System.out.println("OnPostExecute ,Done"); before  TextView txtIP= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtIP); and after txtIP.setText(result + "\n"); in both place

Comment: The first println triggered, the second println don't. It's okay, the data always successfully sent. Thanks for the suggestion. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use AsyncTask like this :

First have it nested in your class, it should look similar to :

```
private class Communicator extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    String tmp;
    String err;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground() {

        try {
                socket = new Socket("192.168.1.4", 9092);
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Hello server!");


         } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (dataOutputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataOutputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (dataInputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataInputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
         txtIP.append(dataInputStream.readUTF() + "\n");            


    }
}
```

When you have AsyncTask,you can start it like this :

```
...
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Communicator c=new Communicator();
c.execute();
}
....
```

Comment: txtIP.append(dataInputStream.readUTF() + "\n"); wont work inside doInBackground()

Comment: txtIP.append(dataInputStream.readUTF() + "\n"); is not accessable from  doInBackground()

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But there's seems to be a problem with your solution. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try  to implement this code in your app

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Object> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {



            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            //do hard work here
                                return params;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {



            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask must be subclassed to be used. The subclass will override at least one method (doInBackground(Params...)), and most often will override a second one (onPostExecute(Result).)

Here is an **example** of subclassing:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Once created, a task is executed very simply:

```
 new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

for more details refer below links...

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html